# Oracle SQL suming value without using aggregate function

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate-functions, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am studying for my SQL class and I'm stuck on a about writing a SQL query without using aggregate functions.

For example, we have table item.

```
item_id | price
1       | 10
2       | 20
3       | 40
```

I can sum up the prices for the various items using the `SUM` function to get a value of 70

```
SELECT SUM(price)
  FROM item
```

How can I get the total price without using any aggregate functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use analytic functions, you can always do

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(price) OVER ()
  FROM item
```

This isn't a sensible reason to use analytic functions since you really do want to use an aggregate function.  But it is valid.

Comment: thanks for answering question, but we shouldn't use aggregate function

Comment: @DcRedwing - OK, that's different from what your question states.  Can you use analytic functions?

Comment: I just can not use aggregate functions. and everything will be fine

Comment: @DcRedwing - OK.  Posted an example using the `SUM` analytic function.